# Visual Studio Code doesn't show errors in editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense, omnisharp

I have a problem with a fresh install of Visual Studio Code. It happens to me before, but I really don't remember the solution to this but i know it can be solved. When I type some code in the editor I should underline it with a red curly line but it doesn't. I read it needs IntelliSense extension but i cant find one for C#. I found out that "C#" (powered by OmniSharp) from Microsoft will work the same but it doesn't. I can't find help anywhere I'm searching for 2 days straight and I'm sure I'm just overthinking it. I hope you know the answer guys.

Comment: Is your language mode set? You should see "C#" in the right end of the bottom bar. If you don't, you can run `Change Language Mode` in the command palette.

Comment: yeah i checked it it says C# and right nexct to it on the left CRLF

Comment: I would also check to make sure the C# extension is installed.

Comment: it is indeed installed. and i reinstalled it like 5 times to make sure but still nothing.. im really out of ideas..

Comment: Are you opening the solution file or just the directory when opening your project?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you selected the same Program.cs to Compile that you also see in your window? Happens to me a lot.